# Capitalize the encoded part of encoded url in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have string urls like this:

```
$url = 'htttp://mysite.com/sub1/sub2/%d8%f01'
```

I'd like to capitalize the encoded part of an url(only `%**` substrings) as per example it is  `'%d8%f01'` so final url will be :

```
htttp://mysite.com/sub1/sub2/%D8%F01
```

Probably using `preg_replace()`, but can't make a correct regex.

Any clues? Thanks!!!

Comment: We'll need to see your regex to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? Can you not split the string at the point you want to capitalise, capitalise that part, and re-join them?

Comment: `htttp` = Hyper Text Turkey Transport Protocol `:-)`

Comment: @JamesWhiteley just too many code and native php function will do it more effective

Comment: @Martin http didn't gave me write the question form validation check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to convert matched `%**` substrings to upper case:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/sub1/sub2/%d8%f01';
echo preg_replace_callback('/(%..)/', function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[1]); }, $url);
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/sub1/sub2/%D8%F01
```

Note this will also work if not all of the URL is encoded, for example:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/sub1/sub2/%cf%81abcd%ce%b5';
echo preg_replace_callback('/(%..)/', function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[1]); }, $url);
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/sub1/sub2/%CF%81abcd%CE%B5
```

**Update**

It is also possible to solve this with a straight `preg_replace`, although the patterns and replacements are quite repetitive as you have to consider all possible hex digits in each position after the `%`:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/sub1/sub2/%cf%81abcd%ce%5b';
echo preg_replace(array('/%a/', '/%b/', '/%c/', '/%d/', '/%e/', '/%f/', 
                        '/%(.)a/', '/%(.)b/', '/%(.)c/', '/%(.)d/', '/%(.)e/', '/%(.)f/'),
                  array('%A', '%B', '%C', '%D', '%E', '%F', 
                        '%$1A', '%$1B', '%$1C', '%$1D', '%$1E', '%$1F'),
                  $url);
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/sub1/sub2/%CF%81abcd%CE%5B
```

**Update 2**

Inspired by @Martin I did some performance testing, and the `preg_replace_callback` solution typically ran about 25% faster than the `preg_replace` (0.0156 seconds vs 0.0220 seconds for 10000 iterations).

Comment: @Martin feel free to post that as answer. You're almost certainly right, but OP was talking about using `preg_replace` so I provided an answer using that...

Comment: @Martin the tricky thing with using `explode` is knowing which parts of the string to uppercase e.g. for `'http://example.com/sub1/sub2/%d8%f01abcd%ef'`

Comment: ~Yes, in light of needing to not change the original *latin* / non-urlencoded data, `preg_replace` is needed and your answer works best. Cheers

Comment: @Nick , somehow I don't see your solution with preg_replace , could you add it,please?

Comment: @Nemo see [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) in Nick's code.

Comment: @Martin , I would love to see a solution with preg_replace . Is it you decided to modify the asked answer? On which permission, may I ask?

Comment: @Nemo See my edit. I've added a straight call to `preg_replace` which will do the job as well.

Comment: @Nick , thank you for providing both solutions and also a performance 
 comparison test results, it was very helpful

Comment: @Nemo no worries - I found it an interesting question to look at.

Comment: And huge thanks to @Martin for inspiring a comparison test to see a world

Comment: Nick, you don't need to use a capture group or `[1]` here, just `~%..~` then `$m[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all knowledgeable with PHP, but here's an example (albeit a bodged-together one which could probably be refactored) of how to do it without Regex. There's no need to use Regex with something like this.

```
$str = "http://example.com/sub1/sub2/%d8%f01";

$expl = explode('%', $str);

foreach ($expl as &$val) {
  if(strpos($val, 'http') === false) {
    $val = '%' . strtoupper($val);
  };
}

print_r(join('', $expl));
```

Comment: This answer suffers the same problem as the other (now-deleted) answer, which is that if part of the last section is not urlencoded, it converts that to upper case as well. For example, `urlencode('αabcdε') = %CE%B1abcd%CE%B5`; your code will change that to `%CE%B1ABCD%CE%B5` which is not the same string.

Comment: @Nick fair enough. Feel free to downvote if this is wrong. I'm very new to PHP so will leave this answer here as an example of what not to do. ;-)

Comment: I'm not a big believer in downvoting answers, I prefer to point out issues and leave it to the poster to decide what to do. It is possible that for someone else who sees this question, the entire last section might be urlencoded, in which case your answer will work fine.